# PDF page rotate not working when pageRotation is not equals to 0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf, rotation, itext

Here I have fully working code to rotate PDF page to specific degree but facing issue when PDF page already rotated.Below I am putting image files in witch case it is working and in witch case facing issue.Here I am passing degree dynamically from user side.

> //When pageRotation is not equals to 0 than it is not working.
> //var pageRotation = reader.GetPageRotation(item.PageNumber);

```
using (var reader = new PdfReader(sourcePdfPath))
{
    foreach (var item in imgModellist.Where(x => x.Degree != 0).ToList())
    {          
        PdfDictionary page = reader.GetPageN(item.PageNumber);
        page.Put(PdfName.ROTATE, new PdfNumber(item.Degree));
    }
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(tempOutputPdfPath, FileMode.Create));
    stamper.Close();
    stamper.Dispose();
    reader.Close();
}
```

**When page Rotation is 0 than it is working fine.**
[image]
**When page Rotation is not equals to 0 than it is not working.**
[image]

Comment: Please share a source PDF for which your code does not work as desired.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B42_k98prWKINFdmb0tfc3FIMFk/view?usp=sharing Please download it from google drive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the code of the OP works in a way: **It *sets* the page rotation *to* the given degrees.**

But that does not seem to be what the OP wants, he seems to want to ***increase* the page rotation *by* the given degrees.**

To do so the original rotation has to be taken into account and the given degrees have to be added to it modulo 360:

```
using (var reader = new PdfReader(sourcePdfPath))
{
    foreach (var item in imgModellist.Where(x => x.Degree != 0).ToList())
    {          
        PdfDictionary page = reader.GetPageN(item.PageNumber);

        PdfNumber formerRotate = page.GetAsNumber(PdfName.ROTATE);
        if (formerRotate != null)
            page.Put(PdfName.ROTATE, new PdfNumber((formerRotate.IntValue + item.Degree) % 360));
        else
            page.Put(PdfName.ROTATE, new PdfNumber(item.Degree));
    }
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(tempOutputPdfPath, FileMode.Create));
    stamper.Close();
    stamper.Dispose();
    reader.Close();
}
```

Depending on the type of that `Degree` member you may have to convert its value to `int` first.

Answer (score 0):

mkl has given the great answer and it is working fine. He is absolutely right 
"To do so the original rotation has to be taken into account and the given degrees have to be added to it modulo 360". I have also use the same approach from another way.

```
using (var reader = new PdfReader(sourcePdfPath))
{
    foreach (var item in imgModellist.Where(x => x.Degree != 0).ToList())
    {               
        int rotation = (item.Degree + reader.GetPageRotation(item.PageNumber)) % 360;
        PdfDictionary page = reader.GetPageN(item.PageNumber);
        page.Put(PdfName.ROTATE, new PdfNumber(rotation));
    }
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(tempOutputPdfPath, FileMode.Create));
    stamper.Close();
    stamper.Dispose();
    reader.Close();
}
```

This is also working fine.